# C# How can I send a text with the data OnDragDrop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I am using a ListView control to hold items that are dropped on another form. I have everything working, except that I also need to include the .Name property of the SelectedIndex, and be able to keep the .Name and .Tag separate in the receiving method.

Where I start the drag:

```
listViewCurves.DoDragDrop(listViewCurves.SelectedItems[0].Tag, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Where I catch the drop:

```
Curve curve = (Curve)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Curve));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any object you want, so this might be a good time to use a `Tuple<string, Curve>`:

```
var selectedItem = listViewCurves.SelectedItems[0];

var data = Tuple.Create(selectedItem.Name, (Curve)selectedItem.Tag);

listViewCurves.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Retrieving end:

```
var data = (Tuple<string, Curve>)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Tuple<string, Curve>));

var name = data.Item1;
var curve = data.Item2;
```

You can read more about the [`Tuple` class here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx).